# How can I convert strings into interger & then subtract between two strings in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char str1[10];

    gets(str1);
    char *token1 = strtok(str1, " ");

    while(token1 != NULL)
    {
        token1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%s\n", token1);
    }

    char str2[10];
    gets(str2);

    char *token2 = strtok(str2, " ");

    while(token2 != NULL)
    {
        token2 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%s\n", token2);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I want to read two strings "Day 9" and "Day 7" from the user and want to calculate the difference between days. So, I have counted `9` and `7` by making this program and now I want to convert those values into interger for performing subtraction but by using either `atoi()` or `sscanf()`, I am not being able to do it.
So, how can I successfully complete this task?

Comment: Simply do a `scanf("%s%d", str1, &day1);` after you declare `int day1,day2` and the same with `str2`, `day2`. No loop needed. Difference being `day2 - day1` (or the opposite!); 3 lines of code (scanf + printf)

Comment: But sir, it has been told that the input formation must be "Day xx". So, I need to read this input in the described formation and that's why I made this loop.

Comment: Your loops have an error: Since they run until the returned pointer is `NULL`, you will call `printf()` with this null pointer in the last turn. -- Are you aware that you can set your format string for `scanf()` to expect "Day"? You might try `scanf("Day %d", &day)`, and don't forget to check the returned value!

Comment: But sir, if I put this null pointer in the last turn, the whole program can not be executed. On the other hand, if I use by following your process, then it does not take input from the users.

Answer (score 0):

in each of the while loops, save the last non-null char*. or use scanf as suggested in the comments.